# capture the "stdin redirected file location string" in c

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, command-prompt, stdin

I am not still sure about the wording in the question, anyway --

I have an executable that takes some values as command line argument and also takes a file from stdin like this:

```
user@pc:~$./executable 0.12345 0.12345 < some/directory/somefile.txt
```

now is there any way I can grab the file location `some/directory/somefile.txt` inside the code ?

what I can do is to modify the code to take the file location as another command line argument, but in that case I need to change a lot of things.

So, it would be better if I could do something like this --

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char cmd_prompt[80];
    char file_location[80];
    grab_command_prompt(cmd_prompt);
    split_and_grab_last_token(cmd_prompt, file_location);
    /* this line below should print: "some/directory/somefile.txt" */
    printf("%s\n", file_location); 
}
```

is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The shell interprets your commandline and, seeing a `<` opens the file for reading, does a [`fork(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) and in the child process, replaces `stdin` with this filehandle using [`dup2(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2) *before* actually executing your program.